# Connecting to LAN through DDNS from said LAN

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, lan, ddns

There is a situation i'm having trouble with:

Let's have two physical places, **PLACE A** and **PLACE B**.

In PLACE A, I have configured the router to have a DDNS **placea.ddns.net**, i have also configured port forwarding for the services i will be using to the specific computer i have them running in, let's just say for sake of the example that my service is using port **9876**.

Then i go to PLACE B, there I access my service through placea.ddns.net:9876, the service is called, it works.

The same doesn't happen when I'm at PLACE A, whenever i call the above mentioned service it doesn't load, eventually giving me the common timeout error. It can't be a firewall, port forwarding or ddns problem since I can access without a problem from outside PLACE A.

Of course it works if on the server i call localhost to the port, or i force the hosts file with the ddns and local ip but that doesn't solve my problem and isn't an option.

The issue persists whenever i call the DDNS from the same network it will redirect to, why, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: in order to use a port-forwarded service from within the LAN its configured on, your router must support NAT Hairpinning (also called NAT Loopback). Hairpinning is not available on most consumer grade routers. if you have an enterprise grade router, you will probably have to enable it.

Comment: Thanks FrankThomas, you and @davidgo explained it perfectly. That also explains why this happens to some clients and in some others it works without any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google "Hairpin NAT".

Your router is only correctly handling traffic on the WAN interface.  There are a few possible solutions - none of which are trivial,

One solution ist o run split DNS - ie map the domain on to the intermal address of the server in your lan (maybe using hosts file).

Another possibility is to get a router that does hairpin NAT.

If the device need not be accessible on the wider Internet, ditch dynamic DNS and use static DNS to the internal address along side a vpn  which connects your LANs.

Comment: Thanks davidgo, you and @FrankThomas on the comment above explained it perfectly. That also explains why this happens to some clients and in some others it works without any issue.